# How can fix ' Error: No application module specified.' on DigitalOcean

Tags: python, django, deployment, devops, digital-ocean

I am getting ' Error: No application module specified. ' error while I'm trying to deploy my django project.

After Successful Build, Digital Ocean is trying deploy it and raise this error after short time.

Can you help me about this? Where should I change?

settings.py >>>

```
"""
Django settings for djcrm project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""


from pathlib import Path
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# .env dosyasını yükle
load_dotenv()

DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG')
# SECRET_KEY'i al
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    "crispy_tailwind",
    'tailwind',

    #local apps
    'leads',
    'agents',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djcrm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djcrm.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.getenv("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": os.getenv("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.getenv("DB_PORT"),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]
STATIC_ROOT = "static_root"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'leads.User'
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/leads"
LOGIN_URL = "/login"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "tailwind"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "tailwind"
```

ss of error >>>

[image]

I tried clear cache and redeploy but It does not work.